# how do i fix this ? TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable AxesSubplot object

Tags: python, pandas

```
s = "sat2019|sat2020".split("|")
j = {x:[random.choice(["EWR","Math"]
                  )for j in range(300)] for x in s}
df = pd.DataFrame(j)
index = np.arange(5)
bar_width = 0.35

fig, ax = plt.subplot()
Sat2019 = ax.bar(index,df["sat2019"].value_counts(),bar_width, label="sat2019")
Sat2020 = ax.bar(index+bar_width,df["sat2020"].value_counts(),bar_width, label="sat2020")
ax.set_xlabel('category')
ax.set_ylabel('incidence')
ax.set_title("diff between years")
ax.set_xticks(index+bar_width/2)
ax.set_xticklabels(["ERW","Math"])
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

the above is my code and below is my error how to do i fix this

fig, ax = plt.subplot()
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable AxesSubplot object
i get this how do i fix this err

Comment: Maybe `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) is just axes. What you want is [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) which returns figure and axes.

After fixing this, you still have some issues in your code, such as `index` length and `df["sat2019"].value_counts()` length doesn't match etc.

I recommend plot using [`pandas.DataFrame.plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```py
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = "sat2019|sat2020".split("|")

j = {x:[random.choice(["EWR","Math"]) for j in range(300)] for x in s}

df = pd.DataFrame(j)

ax = pd.concat([df["sat2019"].value_counts(), df["sat2020"].value_counts()], axis=1).plot.bar()

ax.set_xlabel('category')
ax.set_ylabel('incidence')
ax.set_title("diff between years")

plt.show()
```

[image]

This is also suitable for the case when one of your `sat` column have extra types.

```py
df.loc[0, 'sat2019'] = 'test1'
df.loc[0, 'sat2020'] = 'test2'

ax = pd.concat([df["sat2019"].value_counts(), df["sat2020"].value_counts()], axis=1).plot.bar()
```

[image]